# python call with php: ImportError - no module named dbfread

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, shell-exec

I want to call a python-script with php which loads an dbf-file.
In php I call the script:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python getData.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

The python-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
sys.path.insert(6, "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
from dbfread import DBF

def getFile(src):
  table = DBF(dst)
```

When I call the python-script in console it works. When I call it with php the module dbfread is ot found:

```
ImportError: No module named dbfread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getData.py", line 6, in <module>
    from dbfread import DBF
ImportError: No module named dbfread
```

I tried to set a new sys-path so the sys-paths (console and php call) are the same, unfortunately without success.

Comment: Are you sure the php script has permissions to access the files under `/home/pi`? If the php script is run by Apache, then its user/group is most likely `www-data` or `http`.

Comment: The user of the python-script is pi and the user of the php script is also pi. When I call the python script only with an echo, it works. Only with the import of dbfread it crashes.

Comment: You could try printing `sys.path` and `sys.modules` from both to see if there's any differences. Maybe environment variables are different?